# Fixing bones/armatures

Tags: armature, bones

Looking at the attached picture, I am trying to obtain the example on the right by just rotating 'BONE'
Is there a way of fixing the end of 'BONE.002' to the point shown with the grease pencil?

*[image: emphasized text]*

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do it; a couple of them:

- set a copy rotation constraint on the bone.002, targeting Bone and a copy rotation on the upper bone (local space, if something reotates in a weird direction check axis view in the armature propreties and set the appropriate bone roll to every bone in edit mode).

[image]

- extrude a new bone from the upper bone and set it as target of an IK constraint of bone.002, lenght 1; set the upper bone to copy the rotation of "bone" as the previous example.

[image]